# Newtonsoft.JSON chokes on deserializing object that's surrounded by double quotes in an array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing a `List<UserDataJson>` using Newtonsoft.JSON and then writing to a file. Here is the class:

```
private class UserDataJson
{
    public UserDataJson() { }

    public UserDataJson(string path)
    {
        Location = path;
        Opacity = 1;
    }

    public UserDataJson(IUserData userData)
    {
        Location = userData.Location;
        Opacity = userData.Opacity;
    }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public double Opacity { get; set; }
}
```

The code that serializes and writes:

```
private static readonly string _userDataFile = Path.Combine(_programDataFolder, "userdata.json");

...

public void SaveData(IReadOnlyCollection<IUserData> userData)
{
     File.WriteAllText(_userDataFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData.Select(Serialize).ToList(), Formatting.Indented));
}

private static string Serialize(IUserData userData) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserDataJson(userData));
```

With one element, this produces a `_userDataJson` file that looks like the following:

```
[
  "{\"Location\":\"C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\Documents\\\\test.txt\",\"Opacity\":1.0}"
]
```

However, when I try to deserialize I get a `JsonSerializationException`:

Deserialization:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDataJson>>(File.ReadAllText(_userDataFile).Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Exception:

`{"Error converting value \"{\"Location\":\"C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\test.txt\",\"Opacity\":1.0}\" to type 'Company.App.Wpf.MainWindow.UserDataService+UserDataJson'. Path '[0]', line 2, position 73."}`

Inner Exception:

`"Could not cast or convert from System.String to Company.App.Wpf.MainWindow.UserDataService+UserDataJson."`

However, when I remove the escape-character `\` from the double quotes and remove the double quotes from around the object as a whole, then it deserializes fine.

```
[
  {"Location":"C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\Documents\\\\test.txt","Opacity":1.0}
]
```

Is there any configuration that I should be applying during the serialization or deserialization stage in order to produce a string that can be deserialized into a list of `UserDataJson`?

Comment: That's not an object, that's a plain old string. There's a bug in the code that produced this, not in JSON.NET. Something surrounded by double quotes in JSON is a string, no matter what it contains

Comment: Imagine you take an object, and serialize it as JSON. You get a string, right? So if you add that string to a list and serialize the list, you get something like your JSON above. This is because of this part of your `Serialize` code: `.Select(Serialize)`. This step doesn't seem necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks @Llama, you're correct. If you answer the question in this way then I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you take an object, and serialize it as JSON. You get a string, right? So if you add that string to a list and serialize the list, you get something like your JSON above.

This is because of this part of your Serialize code: `.Select(Serialize)`. This step doesn't seem necessary at all.

Removing that, we get this:

```cs
public void SaveData(IReadOnlyCollection<IUserData> userData)
{
     File.WriteAllText(_userDataFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData, Formatting.Indented));
}

private static string Serialize(IUserData userData) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserDataJson(userData));
```

And this code should now work to deserialize the resultant JSON:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDataJson>>(File.ReadAllText(_userDataFile));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/VUMW38544)

Comment: Just as a note, I had to change `IReadOnlyCollection<IUserData>` to `IReadOnlyList<IUserData>` in order to pass `userData` directly into `SerializeObject`.